# Sink Tailpiece Doesn't Line Up With New Trap - Need Help Making Connection

Tags: plumbing, sink

I am in the process of replacing the bar sink in my office. While I had the sink removed, I decided that it would be a good idea to replace the trap. It was very old. I thought that I would be able to run the tailpiece directly to the trap, but it is off slightly. It seems to be shorter than the old one. I bought 2 traps from Lowe's but neither aligns properly - one has a threaded end, the other does not. I thought that if I used the one with the threaded end, I could connect it directly to the tail piece. What is the best way to get these to align. Should I use 2 90 fittings or something else? I apologize in advance for the questions. I am very new to plumbing, but I feel like it's a skill that I need to learn.

Here are 2 pictures (the pictures show the trap without the threaded end)

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Comment: As an alternative, could I cut the ABS right after the trap, install a coupling, and use that to give me extra length?

Comment: What is the actual connection or end of the pipe on the drain pipe side?

Answer (score 2):

You should not have used that type of trap. You should have used an adjustable P-Trap, which gives a whole bunch of horizontal adjustability:

[image]

It's probably not too late, you could cut that trap off and glue the 1 1/2" male adapter (included in the trap kit) to your drain pipe stub-out.

Each and every suggestion and direction given by the salesperson at the "big box" hardware store should be met with outward courtesy but inward scepticism. A good plumbing shop would have never sent you home with all those glue fittings.

Comment: P.S.- avoid those "flexible" tailpieces, fittings, and traps. Drain lines have a smooth interior for a reason. And yes, every single suggestion etc. on this site should also be met with scepticism...

Comment: Thanks so much for your post. I actually didn't add those glue fittings. That's the original plumbing. I was simply replacing the trap, and the new one didn't line up with my new tailpiece. I would like to get this done right. Do they sell an adjustable t-trap at Lowe's or HD? If not, could I cut the ABS after the trap, add a female coupling, and use that to add horizontal distance?

Comment: They have them at the "big box" stores, but your friendly neighborhood mom-and-pop hardware or plumbing shop would be better able to explain their use, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly seem to have at least one elbow that's not helping in there. Drain connections work by having a slip fit out from the wall combined with the ability to rotate the trap joint, so that you can get everything into a position to connect. The drain pipe does not need to point "at" the tailpiece, so long as it's within reach of the trap joint. Adding that elbow limits your adjustment considerably.

The connections of the trap to the tailpice and wall should be drain compression fittings (threaed fitting with a gasket that allows a slip fit, not involving threaded pipe ends.) You certainly don't want to glue them, they need to able to be disassembled in the event of a clog, diamond ring dropped in the drain, etc.